# How to redirect a dns that point to a ip server to another ip server without changing the dns

Tags: server, dns, ip

Is it possible to bypass the dns propagation to point directly an ip change from the old server to the new server ?

More concrete exemple of what I want to achieve :

www point to ip1 in A record

=> I change the www point to ip2

=> during the dns propagation is it possible to force the ip1 to redirect to the ip2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You could install a proxy to ip1 to forward the requests on to ip2.

Usually such a DNS change is done by setting the TTL (time to live, this specifies how long a DNS answer should be cached) of the record to one minute or even one second. Then wait however long the old TTL was and then update the DNS to point to the new ip and reset the TTL.
This should limit the amount of requests going to ip1 after the change to a minimum.